# How to detect the mfc dialog is maximized or minimized in vc++..?

Tags: visual-c++

```
void  OnSize( UINT nType, int cx, int cy) <br/>
{<br/>
   CDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);<br/>
    CString title ;<br/>
    char wnd_title[256];<br/>
    ::GetWindowText(::GetActiveWindow(),(LPSTR) wnd_title,sizeof( wnd_title));<br/>
  if(title.Find("ABC") != -1){<br/>
        DWORD style = GetActiveWindow()->GetStyle();<br/>
        if (style & WS_MAXIMIZE)<br/>
             MessageBox("Dialog Maximized");<br/>
        else<br/>
             MessageBox(" Dialog Minimized ") ;<br/>

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

void  OnSize( UINT nType, int cx, int cy) 
{
   CDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

```
DWORD style = GetActiveWindow()->GetStyle();
 if (style & WS_MAXIMIZE)
         MessageBox("Dialog Maximized");
  else
         MessageBox(" Dialog Minimized ") ;

}
```

}

It's working by removing the unwanted code line so above code is start working , problem was seem to be that line only .

Answer (score 1):

You have the event type (Minimize/Maximize/Restore) in the nType parameter of OnSize callback.

You can handle that with something like this,

```
void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    switch (nType) 
    {
     case SIZE_MINIMIZED:
       //dialog is minimized
     break;

     case SIZE_RESTORED:
       //dialog is restored
     break;

     case SIZE_MAXIMIZED:
       //dialog is maximized
     break;
    }
}
```